Nazi who's a self-hating Jew
Here is the plot of the movie whose title I am looking for.
The main character is a nazi that is actually a self-hated jew; during the movie he becomes more and more involved in politics, but he also meets a girl that causes him to rethink a lot of things about his life and so he starts to love his origins, but he is conflicted because of his political commitment and fears that people would find out about his secret. 
I think this was released in the early 2000's

This could be The Believer (2001) starring Ryan Gosling. From an online synopsis:

Loosely based on a 1965 true story about a Ku Klux Klan member who was exposed as a Jew, The Believer revolves around the conflicted and charismatic neo-Nazi skinhead Daniel Balint (Ryan Gosling). Sophisticated and intelligent, violent and intense, Danny hates Jews. He also is a Jew.
His oratory talent and charisma catch the attention of neo-Fascists Curtis Zampf (Billy Zane) and Lina Moebius (Theresa Russell) [...] Lina’s daughter Carla (Summer Phoenix) seduces Danny. Initially, the relationship is sexual, but it becomes more complex when she discovers the Torah in Danny’s bedroom and begs him to teach it to her. Supposedly, Carla wants to learn to “know the enemy better,” but as her preoccupation with Danny’s teachings increases, so does his own rabbinic role. 

Here's the trailer:



